# Restricting record level access in role hierarchy

Tags: profile, security, role-hierarchy

If i set the OWD for Account as private and if i create a public group and add some users into that and create a sharing rule for giving read and write access to that public group then managers of the those users in the group will also have read and write access (Because of role heirarchy) right.?

so How do i restrict access to the managers in this scenario?

Answer (score 1):

There is a setting "Grant Access Using Hierarchies" on group by which you can prevent flow of access to upper in hierarchy of users of group.
You can disable that:

[image]

Once you disable that then access will be restricted to the users of group only.
By default this comes as checked while creating group, you need to specifically uncheck it.

Ref : https://help.salesforce.com/htviewhelpdoc?id=creating_and_editing_groups.htm&siteLang=en_US

Hope this helps.

Comment: My guess is... in this situation since we are talking about standard object Account unchecking the " Grant Access Using Hierarchies" box while creating a public group won't help ... it will still give access to the higher roles as by default for standard objects that is the case ... again I haven't tried this.... but that is what the logic and the documentation speaks...

Answer (score 0):

you uncheck the "Grant access using hierarchies" in the sharing settings if possible but you cannot do it for Account. As per your comments it is not possible AFAIK to do

[image]

Comment: That will remove role heirachy access completely  to that object right.I want restrict access only this scenario.

Comment: U cant uncheck for Standard objects.

Comment: @nagachandrakn - Then you are out of luck. and correct you cannot for some standard objects including account. I forgot u stated account

Comment: Is there any other way ? Apex ? validation Rule? Anything?

Comment: @nagachandrakn - You could do it with visual force BUT it would have to be an override of the View button on account. And it would replace the view for ALL accounts. Your call if the effort is worth it for one specific scenario. But you are left with holes like they can search for it, see it in list views and reports, etc