# Opportunity Access with Community Roles

Tags: community, permissions

I want to set up the following scenario:

```
Manager A
  User A1
    Opportunity 1
    Opportunity 2
  User A2
    Opportunity 3
    Opportunity 4

Manager B
  User B1
    Opportunity 5
    Opportunity 6
  User B2
    Opportunity 7
    Opportunity 8
```

In this scenario, Manager A can see Opportunities 1-4, but not Opportunities 5-8. User A1 can only see Opportunity 1-2, etc.

I thought setting Users as Partner User Role and Managers as Partner Manager Role would behave this way but it is not. Managers can see Opportunities 1-8. ORG wide defaults are set to Private. User A1 is the owner of Opportunity 1 and 2.

How do I set things up so I get the desired results?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer found here: [Restricting record level access in role hierarchy](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/60833/restricting-record-level-access-in-role-hierarchy)

You cannot prevent granting access through hierarchies on Opportunities. Since I have a small community so I just put Users and Managers in the same role and set up sharing groups. User A1 and A2 were in one group and they share with Manager A, Users B1 and B2 are in another group and they share with Manager B.